# Why do I have to access my Redux state like "state.topicsReducer.topics"?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've successfully created a redux store using createSlice from @reduxjs/toolkit as follows:

```
const initialState = {
    topics: {
        '123': {
            id: '123',
            name: 'example topic',
            icon: 'icon url',
            quizIds: ['456']
          }
    }
}

const options = {
    name: 'topics',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        addTopic: (state, action) => {
            return {
                ...state,
                topics: {
                    ...state.topics,
                    [action.payload.id]: action.payload
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When creating a selector I found that I have to do the following:

```
export const selectTopics = state => state.topicsReducer.topics;
```

Why do I need the "topicsReducer"? In my course I've always seen state accessed like 'state.topics'. Did I mess something up in my options variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you pass the `reducers` object to [combineReducers(reducers)](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) or [configureStore](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) like this:

```js
combineReducers({ topics: topicsReducer });

// or

configureStore({ reducer: { topics: topicsReducer } })
```

The state shape will be `{ topics }`. Then you can create selector like:

```js
export const selectTopics = state => state.topics;
```